# How to set more than one Angular2 var in Jquery onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular2-forms

I am unable to assign more than one var in jquery in Angular2.

what I am doing is:

```
jQuery('.source-select').on('change',(e) => this.updateForm.value.sources = jQuery(e.target).val().split('--')[0]);
```

this is working prefectly but I want to assigned splited value of index [1] to another object as:

```
  jQuery('.source-select').on('change',(e) => this.updateForm.value.sources = jQuery(e.target).val().split('--')[0]
   ,(e) => this.selected_text = jQuery(e.target).val().split('--')[1]
   );
```

But at this time I am this.selected_text is set but not this.updateForm.value.sources . Any guess what I am doing wrong.

*** I tried using on change twice and that is working fine but I dont think its good to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand your question but why don't you use it ike this?

```
 jQuery('.source-select').on('change',function(e){
    this.updateForm.value.sources = jQuery(e.target).val().split('--')[0];       
    this.selected_text = jQuery(e.target).val().split('--')[1];        
});
```

Comment: I tried this already but I got Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at  updateForm.value I think.

Comment: When you use this with an event 
          this === e.currentTarget will return true
and 
          this === e.target will return true if currentTarget and target are the same. Maybe you are not using the values yout think with "this".